# jaxp object caching for MessageFactory

Tags: java, caching, dom, jaxp, saaj

Can the **javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory** be reused?
I.e.

```
msgFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
```

Can I cache msgFactory and reuse it to create new SOAPMessages as needed?
Also should the `msgFactory.createMessage();` be synchronized if it is ok to reuse msgFactory in the code?

**UPDATE:**
Also in single threaded-code, could I store msgFactory to create SOAPMessages over and over, so as not to create a new instance of MessageFactory each time
Thanks

Comment: The javadoc don't say one way or another, which is unfortunate. I suspect a `MessageFactory` is thread-safe, since that's the convention, but it's hard to be 100% sure.

Comment: @scaffman:But in single threaded-code, could I store msgFactory to create SOAPMessages over and over, so as not to create a new instance of MessageFactory each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing in the javadoc to say that instances of `MessageFactory` are thread-safe, so I wouldn't make that assumption.

However, within a single thread, there's nothing to stop you re-using a `MessageFactory` instance over and over again.

Comment: Could I also synchronize access to msgFactory to get a SOAPMessage per thread?

Comment: @user384706: I suppose so, yes, but you'd have to synchronize it manually