# javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory's instance is thread-safe?

Tags: java, soap

Anyone knows whether javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory's instance is thread-safe or not?

I can't find any documentation related to it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203071/jaxp-object-caching-for-messagefactory/4204035#4204035

Answer (score 2):

If you see no documentation on whether something is thread-safe you should assume that is it not. This will prevent a lot of headache if you assume it is and it is not.