# WebSphere 8 memory leaks

Tags: java, soap, memory-leaks, websphere, apache-axis

I have an application deployed to WebSphere 8.5 (the app is developed using java8/Spring 4) and every day I get many dump files, so I decided to analyze it using Eclipse Memory Analyzer and the result is:

[image]

The problem is I do not use axis for calling web service, I only use Jersy for Rest Web Services and
The default jdk class SoapConnection for soap web services, here is some code examples:
For Soap :

```
public String soapBind(List<ContextItem> dic, String serviceId, String urlWs, String applicationId) throws SOAPException, Exception {
    try {
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
        SOAPMessage msg = soapCall(dic, serviceId, applicationId); // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server

        String url = urlWs;
        LOGGER.info("CALLING WS ....");
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(msg, url);

        // print SOAP Response
       
        //soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        soapResponse.writeTo(out);
        soapConnection.close();

        String strMsg = new String(out.toByteArray());
        LOGGER.info("Response SOAP Message: {}",strMsg);
        return strMsg;

    } catch (SOAPException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

For Rest :

```
Client client = Client.create();
 WebResource webResource = client
 .resource(urlFicheClientProf);
//
 ServiceContext serviceContext = this.getServiceContext();
//
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

 ClientResponse response = webResource
 .queryParam("customerId", radical)
 .queryParam("serviceContext",
 URLEncoder.encode(mapper.writeValueAsString(serviceContext),
 "UTF-8"))
 .post(ClientResponse.class);
```

I am wondering why the Axis.Client Out of memory has occurred and how can I fix it. If anyone could help me figure it out I would be very grateful .

Comment: You could try creating a single `SOAPConnectionFactory` instance instead of creating a new one every time.

Comment: should i define it as a static variable ? i think creating single instance may introduce multithreading problems ?

Comment: Yes, you should define it as a static variable. And it should be thread-safe (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36229337/12763954)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using RestTemplate instead of SOAPConnection fixed the memory leaks :

```
   final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add("Content-Type", "text/xml");
            final HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(message, headers);
            final String result = restTemplate.postForObject(wsUrl, request, String.class);
            return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question: Why does Apache Axis2 get used when you use the default JDK class SOAPConnection?
The class SOAPConnection is actually just a part of an API that could have different implementations. In your case WebSphere provides an implementation of this API based on Apache Axis2, that's why you are seeing objects of those classes lingering.
The [SOAPConnection Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPConnection.html) state:

> The SOAPConnection class is optional. Some implementations may not implement this interface in which case the call to SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance() (see below) will throw an UnsupportedOperationException.

About the second part of your question, I have a hypothesis. In the Javadocs I could not find if a call to *SOAPConnection.close()* is mandatory, but usually resource classes with a *close()* method do require cleaning up or else they create memory or other resource leaks.
Your code does call *close()*, however if an exception occurs somewhere before closing the connection, the execution would jump straight to *catch (...)* and the connection will not be cleaned up, thus creating a memory leak. Maybe this happens every time a SOAP call throws an exception and this leaked the memory you are observing.

You could solve this by using a try-resource-close pattern described here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html
Try the following change in your code.

**Edit**:

```
public String soapBind(List<ContextItem> dic, String serviceId, String urlWs, String applicationId) throws SOAPException, Exception {
    try {
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        try (MySOAPConnection mySoapConnection = new MySOAPConnection(soapConnectionFactory)) {
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = mySoapConnection.connection;
            SOAPMessage msg = soapCall(dic, serviceId, applicationId); // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server

            String url = urlWs;
            LOGGER.info("CALLING WS ....");
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(msg, url);

            // print SOAP Response
           
            //soapResponse.writeTo(System.out);
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            soapResponse.writeTo(out);
            
            String strMsg = new String(out.toByteArray());
            LOGGER.info("Response SOAP Message: {}",strMsg);
            return strMsg;
        }
    } catch (SOAPException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}

public class MySOAPConnection implements AutoCloseable {

    public final SOAPConnection connection;
    
    public MySOAPConnection(SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory)
    {
        this.connection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        this.connection.close();            
    }
}
```

Note that when you use try-resource-close, the *close()* method should not be called explicitly, otherwise you would get double *close()*!

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried to use try-resource-close but the compiler shows me an error :  https://i.ibb.co/PDKm9gL/image.png any idea ?

Comment: Sorry, I noticed that and edited the post. Can you try the second example?

Comment: Now it works, I will deploy the war in the Websphere hopefully I will not have any dump file

Comment: Good luck! Please do report back if the memory leaks were fixed by that.

Comment: unfortunately its not working :(  I am still getting many dump files

Comment: i will try using Spring RestTemplate for calling SOAP ws instead of SOAPConnection